# Как разместить иконку приложения (или процесса) на панели задач?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как разместить иконку приложения (или процесса) на панели задач?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функцией [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa922175.aspx) добавляете, удаляете и изменяете значок. [NOTIFYICONDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx) - структура для хранения значка.

Comment: Там по ссылке `Shell_NotifyIcon` есть пример.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте компонент CoolTrayIcon (либо TJvTrayIcon).

1. Загружаете компонент.
2. Добавляете его на форму.
3. В свойствах задаете иконку.
4. В свойствах выставляете значение IconVisible в true.

Чтобы скрыть программу в трей:

```
CoolTrayIconX.HideMainForm;
```

Чтобы показать программу из трея:

```
CoolTrayIconX.ShowMainForm;
```

Если не хочется компонент, можно все сделать самому, используя Windows API функцию Shell_NotifyIcon.

Comment: Спасибо. Первое оптимально для Delph, второе - на все случаи.